# CodeIgniter - Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name

Tags: php, codeigniter

Создал свою библиотеку для добавления новых пользователей.

```
class Register
{
    private $CI;
    public function add_new_user()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_is_email_exist');
        if ($CI->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $insert_data = array('email' => $email);
            $CI->new_data->add_user($insert_data);
        }
    }
    private function is_email_exist($email)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $email_result = '';
        $query = $CI->check->find_email($email);
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $email_result = $row['email'];
        }
        if ($email_result == $email)
        {
            $CI->form_validation->set_message('is_email_exist', 'Such email already exist!');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Настроил автозагрузку для **form_validation** и моделей **check, new_data**. При отправке формы на месте где должны выводиться ошибки(если они есть),выводится **Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Username.(is_username_exist)**. Как сделать чтобы выводилась правильное сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 0):

Затрудняюсь указать на ошибку в приведенном коде, но будет полезно сказать, что создание кастомного колбека в Вашем случае ни к чему. Просто используйте [is_unique](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference)